# Angular2 RC5 Prevent child component from recreating when (click) is called

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular2.RC5 with angular-cli.webpack.8.

I have list of items build with component and "child" components. I want to implement some behavior for child components to change class when I click something inside it. But when (click) event is triggered child component is recreated and all changes are going to waste. This child component looks something like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'red-key-list-folder',
  template: `
      <a (click)="isVisible = true">
       CLICK TO OPEN
      </a>
      <div [ngClass]="{'show': isVisible}">
       HIDDEN CONTENT
      </div>
  `
})
export class KeyListFolderComponent {

  @Input() somethingFromParentComponent: Object = {};

  isVisible: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

I tried adding

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

to Component metadata but it didn't work either.

My Parent component looks more less like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  template: `
      <div>
        <template ngFor let-key [ngForOf]="list">
          <red-key-list-folder [somethingFromParentComponent]="something">
          </red-key-list-folder>
        </template>
      </div>
  `
})
export class ListComponent {

  something: Object = {};

  list = [
    1, 2, 3
  ];

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

Any idea how to prevent that component from reloading on this click event?

Comment: I think you should add the code that shows how the child is added to the parent. That the child is recreated on click is weird and I'm pretty sure it is caused by some of your code and not by Angular2.

Comment: I'll add this to post.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the anchor tag to something else, say a button?  I've seen angular pick up an anchor tag (even if an href isn't specified) and reload (since it thinks it's a link, but isn't sure where it's a link to) because of a click on it.  If it has to be an anchor tag, then try adding `role="button"` to it.  I'm not sure if that's a bootstrap specific role, but it's a recommended action for not link anchor tags.

Comment: I tried with `<a>`, `<button>` and `<span>` also with this `role="button"` but it changes nothing. Every time click event is triggered whole list is reloaded (I added `console.log()` to the constructor to be sure that's the case). Funny thing is that if I do such click event in parent component than it didn't reload it so I think it has to be related with how angular2 deals with nested components.